# Can I get all schemas through SQL query?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to get all the schemas that exist on the DB server?

Comment: `select * from information_schema.schemata` but even though it has a column `catalog_name` you will never see a value that id different from the current database in there. Postgres does not support cross-database queries

Comment: and how to do this? I dev application  in Java and have to get all schemas from specified database :c

Comment: Just run that statement, it will return all schemas.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve what you need with a combination of shell scripting and psql command. Can you expand on your requirements, type of output, and the consumer of the data?

Comment: I already solved this problem ,ty you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT schema_name 
FROM information_schema.schemata 
WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg%'
AND schema_name NOT LIKE 'information_schema'
AND catalog_name LIKE 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
```

Two `NOT LIKE` clauses are to avoid system schemas